# Display Audio Attachment URL

Tags: attachments, audio

To get the image url from a Post Thumbnail in WordPress to display it in a template, I would use:

```
<?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'large'); $image_url = $image_url[0]; ?><?php echo $image_url;?>
```

I'm trying to do the same for a MP3 uploaded to a post.

I had a snippet a while back to get it done, but I don't know what happened to it.

How can I do the same for a MP3 uploaded to a post?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you **do** know the attachment `$id`, you can use [**`wp_get_attachment_url()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url):

- `<?php wp_get_attachment_url( $id ); ?>`

If you need to determine the attachment `$id`, you can use [**`get_posts()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts):

```
global $post;
$audio_attachments = get_posts( array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'audio'
) );
```

If you have multiple (or unknown number of) audio attachments, you can loop through to get the URLs:

```
$audio_attachment_urls = array();

foreach ( $audio_attachments as $audio_attachment ) {
    $audio_attachment_urls[] = wp_get_attachment_url( $audio_attachment->ID );
}
```

Or, if you know there is only one audio attachment:

```
$audio_attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $audio_attachments[0]->ID );
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it's not displaying the MP3 URL.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you try it? What data did you get returned at each point? e.g. what did you get returned for `$audio_attachments`?

Comment: What did you figure out? Please post your solution as an answer.